# Disable second subradio button when chose 1 option and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem, hope You can help me. 
I have 2 option with sub radios.

1 - Option A

---- variant 1

---- variant 2

---- variant 3

2 - Option B

---- variant 4

---- variant 5

---- variant 6

[Link to my code](http://tinyurl.com/nbovduo)

User have to choose Option A or Option B

If chosen option A and for example variant 1
and change mine to Option B and other variant 4 or 5 or 6
then variant 1, 2, 3 should be disabled bot not Option A
and vice versa

Is somebody decide to return to Option A from option B and leave some variant 4 or 5 or 6
and choose variant 1 or 2 or 3
then Option B should be enable but variant 4, 5, 6 should not be selected and should be disabled 
only variants from Option A should be enabled

I mean. User can choose between two Options A r B
If he will select Option A and some variant from 1 to 3 and click to Option B,
variants form 1-3 should be automatically deselected.

If he will select Option B and some variant from 4 to 6 and click to Option A,
variants form 4-6 should be automatically deselected.

Thanks for help !

Comment: where is your code..? what have you tried..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ae65Z/

```
$(function () {
    $("#optionCustomer1, #optionCustomer2").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        switch(id) {
            case "optionCustomer1":
                $("#variantCustomer1, #variantCustomer2, #variantCustomer3").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#variantCustomer4, #variantCustomer5, #variantCustomer6").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#variantCustomer4, #variantCustomer5, #variantCustomer6").prop('checked', false);
                break;
            case "optionCustomer2":
                $("#variantCustomer1, #variantCustomer2, #variantCustomer3").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#variantCustomer1, #variantCustomer2, #variantCustomer3").prop('checked', false);
                $("#variantCustomer4, #variantCustomer5, #variantCustomer6").prop('disabled', false);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```